# Is it natural and correct to say "sugary foods give me acne"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it natural and correct to say *sugary food gives me acne*? For example:

> Sugary foods **give me** acne, so I try to steer clear of them.

If it sounds off, would it be more natural to say the following?

> Sugary foods **cause** acne **on** me, so I try to steer clear of them.

What is the most natural way to say it?

Comment: First way is best and works for most similar usages.  *Wine gives me a headache.  Garlic gives me bad breath.  Poorly fitting shoes give me blisters.*  For an alternate usage use *I get A from B* instead of *A causes B in/on me*.  For example *I get acne from sugary foods.  I get a headache from wine.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is best and works for most similar usages.

> Wine gives me a headache.

> Garlic gives me bad breath.

> Poorly fitting shoes give me blisters.

For an alternate usage I would suggest a more active construct such as **I get A from B** instead of **A causes B in/on me**.

> I get acne from sugary foods.

> I get a headache from wine.